# Problem of printing 2 decimals by using "{.2f}".format

Tags: python

I want to round up two decimals, by using "{0:2f}".format(), but my answer could not round up to 2 decimals. So which syntax is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
bill=input("What was the total bill?")
percentage=input("What percentage tip would you like to give?")
percentage_num=int(percentage)/100
people=input("How many people to spill the bill?")
each=(int(bill)*1+percentage_num)/int(people)
each="{0:2f}".format(each)
print(f"Each person should pay : {each}")
```

Comment: Use ".2f" with a leading decimal point

Answer (score 0):

You missed the dot in front of the 2:

```
percentage=input("What percentage tip would you like to give?")
percentage_num=int(percentage)/100
people=input("How many people to spill the bill?")
each=(int(bill)*1+percentage_num)/int(people)
each="{0:.2f}".format(each)  # use .2f to round to two decimals
print(f"Each person should pay : {each}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution using round:

```
percentage=input("What percentage tip would you like to give?")
percentage_num=int(percentage)/100
people=input("How many people to spill the bill?")
each=(int(bill)*1+percentage_num)/int(people)
print(f"Each person should pay : {round(each, 2)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
each = f'{each:0.2f}'
```